# What does $\forall x \exists y P(x, y) $ mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Considering U the universal set, which contains the elements 0, 1, 2..., does $\forall x \exists y P(x, y) $ mean

$\exists yP(0,y) \wedge \exists yP(1,y) \wedge \exists yP(2,y)...$

or

$\forall x[x \in U \rightarrow \exists yP(x,y)]=$
$[0 \in U \rightarrow \exists yP(0,y)] \wedge [1 \in U \rightarrow \exists yP(1,y)] \wedge [2 \in U \rightarrow \exists yP(2,y)]...$  ?

Comment: The first one is close to what it means. The second does not make any sense because there is "$U$", but no "$U$" is defined.

Comment: If your universe is named $U$ and $U$ explicitly includes the elements $0,1,2,\dots$, then both are correct but it need not be the case that your universe includes elements named $0,1,2,\dots$.  We could be talking about the universe being the set of all people and $P(x,y)$ is the statement that $x$ is loved by $y$, i.e. the statement reads "For all people in the world there is someone that loves them."  There isn't a "person named 0" and so on...

Comment: I thought $\forall x \exists y P(x,y)$ was the same $\forall x \in U \exists y \in U P(x,y)$, being U the universal set, which, in my example, includes the elements 0,1,2....

Comment: "*which in my example includes the elements $0,1,2,\dots$*" If that were the case for your example then you should have said so.  There are many contexts where that would not make sense as the universal set...  Of course, the premises of your implications such as $0\in U\to$ are all unnecessary since as you say you are working under the impression that $0\in U$ is automatically true so we don't need to have that as a hypothesis in an implication.  If your universe was $\{0,1,2,\dots\}$ you could have written it as $[\exists y P(0,y)]\wedge [\exists y P(1,y)]\wedge \dots$

Comment: Of course... there are those universal sets which are not countable so it is impossible to write that in those cases... which is why we do so with the $x$ being arbitrary instead... $\forall x \exists y P(x,y)$.  In doing so, we cover all of the cases that $x$ could be at once rather than having to list them all out if such a thing were even possible to begin with, and in doing so we don't even need to bother ourselves with considering what the possible values of $x$ might even look like.

Comment: If it is so, then why Velleman in _How to Prove It?_ states that $\forall x \in A P(x)$ stands for $\forall x[x \in A \rightarrow P(x)]$ ?

Comment: Because $A$ might be a subset of the universal set rather than the universal set itself.  If the universal set were all real numbers and $A$ was the set of all positive real numbers, you could say $\forall x\in\Bbb R[x\in\Bbb R^+\to \exists y\in \Bbb R:~ x=y^2]$, that is for all positive real numbers there is a real number that when squared is the original number.

Comment: @TylerD007: Because $A$ is in general not the universal set.

Comment: I mean, if $\forall x \in A P(x)$ is the same $\forall x [x \in A \rightarrow P(x) ]$, then $\forall x \exists y P(x,y)$ would have to be equivalent to $\forall x [x \in U \rightarrow \exists y P(x,y)]$. Or is there some notation issue that I am missing?

Comment: Yes... and you could include the $x\in U\implies$ part of the statement if you so insist... but it is redundant to do so.  Since we are talking about an $x$ from the universal set in the first place it is redundant to tell us that $x$ is an element from the universal set as a hypothesis in an implication.  If we say that $x$ is an element from a universal set then saying that $x$ is an element from a universal set a second, fourth, or hundredth time is pointless since it has already been said that $x$ is an element from a universal set.

Comment: While $\text{True}\implies P(x)$ is indeed equivalent to $P(x)$, the latter uses far fewer symbols and does not involve unnecessary notation and so it is preferable to use.

Comment: Thank you. Now, I will change my question a little bit. Is $\forall x \in A \exists y \in B P(x,y)$ equivalent to $\forall x [x \in A \rightarrow \exists y \in B P(x,y)]$ ?

Comment: Yes.$~~~~~~~~~$

Comment: Then both forms in my original question are indeed logically equivalent, or not?

Comment: As stated in my very first comment, yes, all three of the expressions are equivalent, however that is again under the assumption that $U$ is the name of your universal set and $U$ contains the elements $0,1,2,\dots$

Answer (score 3):

It means

$$\begin{array} {c} 
\bigg(P(0, 0) \text{ or } P(0, 1) \text{ or } P(0, 2) \text{ or } P(0, 3) \text{ or } \dots\bigg) \\
\text{and} \\
\bigg(P(1, 0) \text{ or } P(1, 1) \text{ or } P(1, 2) \text{ or } P(1, 3) \text{ or } \dots\bigg) \\
\text{and} \\
\bigg(P(2, 0) \text{ or } P(2, 1) \text{ or } P(2, 2) \text{ or } P(2, 3) \text{ or } \dots\bigg) \\
\text{and} \\
\vdots \\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point out how this can be interpreted intuitively. In words, what the statement means is that for every value of x, there is some value of y such that P(x, y) is satisfied.

The answer that DanielIV has written is exactly this if we take our universe to be the natural numbers, but we could have very different objects in our universe. As a sort of silly example let our univese be the set of functions:

$$
U = \{0, 1, q, \dfrac{q^2}{2}, \dfrac{q^3}{2\cdot3}, , \dfrac{q^4}{2\cdot3\cdot4}\, \dots, \dfrac{q^n}{n!}\}
$$

If we define P(x, y) to mean that x is the derivative of y, then we see that we have satisfied your orginal statement. In this context, it means that for every function x in our universe, there exists a function y also in our universe that is the derivative of x.

Why go to all this trouble to make this example? Because it is important to understand our assumptions, especially about the universe of objects under consideration.

Comment: Thank yoy, Sirch. My question now is how to prove the logical equivalence of the statements  $\forall x \in A \exists y \in B P(x,y)$ and $\forall x [x \in A \rightarrow \exists y \in B P(x, y)]$.

Comment: Again, let's try to translate the symbols to words. 

1 says that for all x in set A, there exists a y in set B such that P(x, y)

For 2, it appears that the set A is given by $\{x_0, x_1, \dots\}$. This statement is going through every option for x and saying that for each of these options there exists a y such that P(x, y)

3 is yet another way of stating the same thing in a more verbose presentation. It says that for every x, x being in A implies that there exists y such that P(x, y).